# Cannot set property '0' of undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The function works if i change the if(x==0) to if(y==0).
The purpose of this is to later use the 2D array and display some images.
I have the 2D array so i can create a bomberman like background.

```
var test = [
  []
];

var tile = {
  width: can.width / 15,
  height: can.height / 15,
}

function render() {

  for (var y = 0; y < 15; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 15; x++) {

      if (x == 0) {
        console.log(x, y);
        var t = {
          width: can.width / 15,
          height: can.height / 15,
        };

        test[y][x] = t;
        test[y][x].posX = x * tile.width;
        test[y][x].posY = y * tile.height;
        test[y][x].num = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Considering `test` only has 1 inner array, that seems like a reasonable output.

Comment: Ohh okay i think i see what you're saying. Im new to JS so didnt know what would be the outcome. Then how would i frame it so i can add values to the positions such as test[1][1].

Comment: you can use .push() to add new elements (which should be arrays) to the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test[0]` is an array, but `test[1]` thru `test[14]` are not defined.  If you want to initialize those other elements, you could do this:

```
for( var i = 0; i < 15; i++ )
    test[i] = []
```

or something like this, although it's harder to read:

```
var test = [ 
    [], [], [], [], [],
    [], [], [], [], [],
    [], [], [], [], []
]
```

Alternatively, you can add array elements as needed rather than pre-allocating them:

```
if( typeof test[y] == 'undefined' )
    test[y] = []
```

Comment: Ohhh okay thanks. Should i put that as a loop at the top of the render function?

Answer (score 0):

See, take a look at your test initialisation,

```
test = [[]]
```

which only have 1 element of empty array, please take a look at your loop, and it will definitely work `if (y == 0)`, because you will access `test[0][0], test[0][1], and so on`

Now, `if(x == 0)`, you cannot really do that because the element is not initiated after index 0. So, `test[1] is basically undefined, and test[1][0] will fail`

Probably the following change will fix your code

```
var test = [];
...
for (var y = 0; y < 15; y++) {
    var el = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
        ...
        var one = t;
        ...
        el.push(one);
    }
    test.push(el);
}
```